# Reading boolean from JSX {} in reducers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, reducers

here is what I have on clicking in console log everything is working perfectly while dispatching

[image]

My code is here to understand which is undefined and which are true and false

```html
   <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>dispatch(add())} className="btn btn-primary mr-1">+</button>

      <button onClick={()=>dispatch(remove())} className="btn btn-primary mr-1">-</button>

      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h1>Toggle {togRed} nor {String(togRed)} not even {togRed + ""}</h1>
      <h1>Testing bool {String(true)} and {false+""}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>dispatch(tog())} className="btn btn-success">Toggle</button>
      {}
    </div>
```

How can I have true and false written after the Toggle  like in console log on clicking the Toggle button

Comment: Do you have `togRed` defined in your component? Show us the whole component.

Comment: The whole thing is in different Components it's impossible to show all of them that would confuse more,but Yes togRed is defined as much as counter, so the counter shows, but togRed doesn't because it's true or false not a string or a number that's the thing

Comment: I doubt that `togRed` is defined in `{String(togRed)}`, because `String(true)` resolves to `"true"`, `String(false)` resolves to `"false"` and `String(undefined)` resolves to `"undefined"` (as it is in your screenshot). Show us at least a part of code from the same component as your code snippet is, where you have `togRed` defined.

Comment: You were right You could add an answer and I will mark it as a right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering boolean value in JSX is straightforward as you would expected.

You have a problem with value of your prop/variable here, `togRed` is probably `undefined` in the part where you are displaying its content:

```js
<h1>Toggle {togRed} nor {String(togRed)} not even {togRed + ""}</h1>
```

Because `String(true)` resolves to `"true"`, `String(false)` resolves to `"false"` and `String(undefined)` resolves to "undefined" (as we can see in rendered text "Toggle nor undefined not even undefined" in your screenshot).